# Invalid column name ' ' on concatenate columns with Laravel 4 Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-4

So I want to prepare a list to place into a combobox with laravel and I wanted to use concatenate to join the value of 3 columns and I can achieve that with this

```
public function deviList() {
        return Device::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(DESC, OS, OS_V) AS FullDesc'), 'DEVI_ID')                        
                        ->where('STATUS', 2)
                        ->orderBy('DESC')
                        ->lists('FullDesc', 'DEVI_ID');
    }
```

However it'd be better to have a space or slash separating the values of the columns so I did it like this, same as some people recomended in some other places:

```
public function deviList() {
        return Device::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(DESC," ",OS," ",OS_V) AS FullDesc'), 'DEVI_ID')                        
                        ->where('STATUS', 2)
                        ->orderBy('DESC')
                        ->lists('FullDesc', 'DEVI_ID');
    }
```

However I get an error saying **SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name ' '** (So I'm guessing unlike the examples given elsewhere, those separations get read as if they were columns?) So how can I concatenate with some sort of separation?

Comment: Can you try switching the quotes so that the SQL statement uses single quotes:  `DB::raw("CONCAT(DESC,' ',OS,' ',OS_V) AS FullDesc")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your SQL Server has `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` turned on, then the double quotes will be used to identify objects, not string literals.  In this case, `" "` would not be a string representing a space, it would be an object (column) represented by a space, which doesn't exist.

Try switching the quotes in your SQL statement:

```
public function deviList() {
    return Device::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(DESC,' ',OS,' ',OS_V) AS FullDesc"), 'DEVI_ID')                        
        ->where('STATUS', 2)
        ->orderBy('DESC')
        ->lists('FullDesc', 'DEVI_ID');
}
```

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with SQL Server, but from what I recall, there isn't a `CONCAT` function available. Instead, you use something like this:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(col1, '') + '' + COALESCE(col2, '')) AS col3 FROM ...
```

I think you can use this as so if your query:

```
public function deviList() {
  return Device::select(DB::raw('(COALESCE(DESC, "") + " " + COALESCE(OS, "") + " " (COALESCE(OS_V, "")) AS FullDesc'), 'DEVI_ID')                        
    ->where('STATUS', 2)
    ->orderBy('DESC')
    ->lists('FullDesc', 'DEVI_ID');
}
```

Unfortuneately, I have no way of testing this, but what it should do is, using `COALESCE()` check if the column is null before concatenating it with a space between, then aliasing it as `FullDesc` for use later.

Hopefully that will work.

Comment: if there wasn't it wouldn't work  with the **CONCAT(DESC, OS, OS_V) AS FullDesc')** but it does just fine, it shows the columns concatenated like I said. I just wanted to also make a separation like a backlash or underscore or space or something for better presentation purposes

Comment: But you're getting a SQL error aren't you? Now I'm confused :P

Comment: I am, but only when I try to add a separation **('CONCAT(DESC," ",OS," ",OS_V) AS FullDesc'), 'DEVI_ID') **

Comment: Ohhh I see. I can understand why \ would break it, as that's an escape charatcer. Try checking the raw output of the query: `$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); $last_query = end($queries); dd($last_query);` and see what it's trying to do, maybe you can better understand it that way.

Comment: I didn't use \ anywhere. And that gives me the login query. Probably because this one failed so it wasn't recorded

Comment: I know you didn't use \ in the example, but you said "slash separating the values" and I was pointing out that \ wouldn't work.